# Get attribute of a class/id and append to text using jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-selectors

I am using Twitter Bootstrap for my current project.
I have a tooltip in which I show the text in the title.
For mobiles I want to append the title with the text. I am able to detect the device using viewport-width

I have added my current code in jsfiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/VenomVendor/FUCkA/2/ 
*Note :  I am not responsible for that dynamically generated URL *F*****  
**Example :**

## For PCs

```
<span class="vee-tooltip-right" title="Asynchronous JavaScript and XML">AJAX</span>
<br>
<span class="vee-tooltip-top" title="JavaScript Object Notation">JSON</span>
<br>
<span class="vee-tooltip-left" title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</span>
```

## For Mobiles - to be done

```
<span class="vee-tooltip-right" title="">AJAX - Asynchronous JavaScript and XML</span>
<br>
<span class="vee-tooltip-top" title="">JSON - JavaScript Object Notation</span>
<br>
<span class="vee-tooltip-left" title="">CSS - Cascading Style Sheets</span>
```

I have managed to get the string in the title using [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) & number of classes using [count](http://api.jquery.com/length/).

Since I have different class names I have used common selector `"span[class*='vee-tooltip-']"`

**I am struck with dynamically fetching the `title` attribute and appending to the same Parent.**

Comment: +1 for epic JSFiddle link XD

Comment: "I have managed to get the string in the title using attr()" / "I am struck with dynamically fetching the title attribute". How can both be true?

Comment: I am struck with dynamically ....... and appending to the same Parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that every time you write `$("span[class*='vee-tooltip-']")` (which should be `^=`, not `*=`, by the way), you are creating a whole new jQuery object. There is no relation between them, so you can't affect the one you want easily.

I would suggest using this:

```
$("span[class^='vee-tooltip-']").each(function() {
    this.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" - "+this.getAttribute("title")));
}
```

Comment: Try `this.removeAttribute("title")` to remove the attribut, or `this.setAttribute("title","")`. Also, you might want to learn about [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/), the JavaScript extension that's so powerful that it's already built-in to all browsers ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.each`

http://jsfiddle.net/raam86/8RjN8/

```
$("span[class*='vee-tooltip-']").each(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    var text = $this.text();
    var title = $this.attr("title");
    $(this).text(text + title);
})
```

Comment: This was the issue that I was getting, first elements title was applied to all the other elements, btw, the accepted answer is the solution.

Comment: @VenomVendor whoops haven't noticed it's the same. Fixed so you'll have jQuery solution for kicks.